# Php + js подобие фреймворка

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, html, javascript

Начал писать некоторое подобие фреймворка, MVC система и AJAX подгрузкой контента. Тут меня приспичило сделать кириллические URL без реврайтов, с этим справился. Теперь проблема в том что некоторые браузеры не очень хорошо относятся к JS и сайт, мягко говоря для становится недоступен, теперь я сделал так, чтобы даже с отсутствуем JS сайт продолжал работать, при чем полностью корректно, но столкнулся с проблемой, как определить поддреживает ли браузер ту или иную функцию, допустим у меня прелоадер для подгрузки css/js кода, во время загрузки что то типа анимации, вот тут та, некоторые браузеры просто нехотят проходить дальше этого пункта. Как же все таки можно сделать проверку, или может что то иное?

Сайт для примера: http://protection.avenger-web.ru/ (Для модераторов: сайт полностью пустой и не являет рекламой)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот прям для вас проект писали - http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Comment: ваш сайт даже в lynx юзабелен, давно такого не видел.

Comment: Не думаю что, там он хорошо работает, но сейчас я занят именно работой сайт без поддержки Jquery или JS вообще.